# Android proguard crashes after enabling google analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, proguard

I activated google analytics for my android application, when I tried to use proguard I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnZTP.png) errors.

What is the solution?

[image]

Comment: Please provide detailled information how did you integrate analytics in your application.

Answer (score 0):

It means that class is obfuscated by proguard.

Personally I always add the generic rule

> -keep class com.google.** { *; }

in my proguard because I only care for obfuscation of my own code. That should fix your error. But if you just want to add that class only it should also work I guess.